# Automated Powerscript for creating github

Tags: powershell

```
Function jay {
    [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, HelpMessage = "Enter the new repository name")]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [string]$Name,

        [string]$Description,

        [switch]$Private,
        [switch]$NoWiki,
        [switch]$NoIssues,
        [switch]$NoDownloads,
        [switch]$AutoInitialize,

        #license templates found at https://github.com/github/choosealicense.com/tree/gh-pages/_licenses
        [ValidateSet("MIT", "apache-2.0", "gpl-3.0", "ms-pl", "unlicense")]
        [string]$LicenseTemplate,

        [Alias("token")]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [string]$UserToken = 'github token here',

        #write full native response to the pipeline
        [switch]$Raw
    )

    Write-Verbose "[BEGIN  ] Starting: $($MyInvocation.Mycommand)"
    #display PSBoundparameters formatted nicely for Verbose output  
    [string]$pb = ($PSBoundParameters | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String).TrimEnd()
    Write-Verbose "[BEGIN  ] PSBoundparameters: `n$($pb.split("`n").Foreach({"$("`t"*2)$_"}) | Out-String) `n" 

    #create the header
    $head = @{
        Authorization = 'Basic ' + $UserToken
    }

    #create a hashtable from properties
    $hash = @{
        name          = $Name
        description   = $Description
        private       = $Private -as [boolean]
        has_wiki      = (-Not $NoWiki)
        has_issues    = (-Not $NoIssues)
        has_downloads = (-Not $NoDownloads)
        auto_init     = $AutoInitialize -as [boolean]
    }

    if ($LicenseTemplate) {
        $hash.add("license_template", $LicenseTemplate)
    }

    $body = $hash | ConvertTo-Json

    Write-Verbose "[PROCESS] Sending json"
    Write-Verbose $body

    #define parameter hashtable for Invoke-RestMethod
    $paramHash = @{
        Uri              = "https://api.github.com/user/repos" 
        Method           = "Post"
        body             = $body 
        ContentType      = "application/json"
        Headers          = $head
        UseBasicParsing  = $True
        DisableKeepAlive = $True
    }

    #should process
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$name [$description]")) {
        $r = Invoke-RestMethod @paramHash

        if ($r.id -AND $Raw) {
            Write-Verbose "[PROCESS] Raw result"
            $r

        }
        elseif ($r.id) {
            write-Verbose "[PROCESS] Formatted results"

            $r | Select-Object @{Name = "Name"; Expression = { $_.name } },
            @{Name = "Description"; Expression = { $_.description } },
            @{Name = "Private"; Expression = { $_.private } },
            @{Name = "Issues"; Expression = { $_.has_issues } },
            @{Name = "Wiki"; Expression = { $_.has_wiki } },
            @{Name = "URL"; Expression = { $_.html_url } },
            @{Name = "Clone"; Expression = { $_.clone_url } }
        }
        else {

            Write-Warning "Something went wrong with this process"
        }

        if ($r.clone_url) {
            $msg = @"

To push an existing local repository to Github run these commands:
-> git remote add origin $($r.clone_url)"
-> git push -u origin master

"@
            Write-Host $msg -ForegroundColor Green

        }
    }

    Write-Verbose "[END    ] Ending: $($MyInvocation.Mycommand)"

}
```

I am working on this Powershell script to accept creating Github repo from my local pc to Github. But every time I try to enter description it fails and provides me this error. Could someone please help me out

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"Requires
>       authentication","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create"}
>       At C:\Users\norep\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:96 char:14

Comment: Do you know what _Requires authentication_ means? I gues you are actually using a GitHub user token in this line: `$UserToken = 'github token here'`

Comment: yes, I am assingning usertoken with my github token id. Requires authentication is when I am trying to send a request to verify if the token is present if no provide error

Comment: I suggest you read and action the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use your Github API token with Basic Authentication, but [according to the Github API v3 documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) that token is an OAuth token. Your header should look like this instead:

```
$head = @{
    Authorization = 'token ' + $UserToken
}
```

You would use the `Basic` auth header if you were providing a base64 encoded string of your username and password (in the format of `USERNAME:PASSWORD`):

```
$basicAuthBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('USERNAME:PASSWORD')
$basicAuthBase64String = [Convert]::ToBase64String( $basicAuthBytes )
$head = @{
  Authorization = "Basic ${basicAuthBase64String"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but it didnt work. It try to provide me the git push url but its not working and not dynamically creating repo in github

Comment: Are you still getting the "requires authorization" error? Have you tried with basic auth to rule out a problem with the token?

Comment: I am not getting request authorization error but it's not allowing me to capture my input like description, licensed but other then that its working fine

Comment: I think that issue probably warrants a new question, since this one is about authentication, which sounds like it's resolved.

Comment: Agreed - it appears you've solved the issue and now there is a new question,

Comment: Thanks guys. I gave you the best answer @BendertheGreatest . Hopefully you can help me with next question too hehe. Thank you so much for your help